# How to update this axios service for being able conditionally decide which API URL to use?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, axios, ecmascript-5

I have the following axis service:

```
   const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
});
```

I need conditionally pass isAdmin from outside for being able to switch the API URL here. How can be it achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple instances for each baseURL and call the instance by `isAdmin` condition. However, you can config the defaults that will be applied to every request.

```
import axios from "axios";
    
/* default config for each request */
axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
axios.defaults.timeout = 1000;

const adminAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/'
});
    
const nonAdminAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://other-some-domain.com/api/'
});
    
    
const getInstance = (isAdmin) => isAdmin ? adminAxios : nonAdminAxios;
```

Answer (score 1):

We could pass in the value into the constructor, and pass it to the `initInstance` method, then return the URL contingent on the value of `isAdmin`.

```js
class AxiosService {
    // ...

  constructor(isAdmin = false) {
    this.initInstance(isAdmin);
  }

  initInstance(isAdmin) {
    this.axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: isAdmin ? '/api/admin/v1' : '/api/v1',
      timeout: 5000
    });
        
        // ...
  }
    
    // ...
}
```

To use these, we'd now go...

```js
const axiosService = new AxiosService(true); // admin url will be used
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. And how can it be achieved in more simpler service like this?

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
});

Comment: It looks like few lines that do the same operation like above long service. Updated question codebase

Comment: @NewTechLover You would do the same thing the "bigger" service is doing, specifically on the line that defines `baseUrl` in the object.

Something like `isAdmin ? 'admin_url_here' : 'regular_url_here'`

Comment: Do you mean doing 2 different  axios.create({...}) with different URLS and exporting them?

Comment: @NewTechLover No, I mean using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to conditionally define the URL based on a condition, such as the user being administrator.

Comment: Yes but how should be passed in axios instance? since axios instance is directly getting used in the api services. It would be great if you update the answer.